# Chrome: Images with transparent backgrounds being unreadable (black on black)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, images

If I try to view an image *in it's own tab* such as the one below using Chrome 39 on Windows 8, all I will see is black. This is because the text (*which is actually an image*) is black, and the background Chrome uses under the image is also black.

However, Firefox 33 does not appear to have this issue, and instead seems to fill the transparency with a grey-ish texture.

Using chrome, click and drag this image to the tab bar to see what I'm talking about:

[image: Black text on transparent background]

What can I do to view an image such as this in its own tab? Clicking on links for certain images often leaves me with all-black tabs, which means I have to view the image outside of the browser. Very inconvenient.

Comment: what os are you on? that pix looks fine for me in chrome 39 ubuntu

Comment: Oops I took out some text and forgot to put back in the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know why you are having compatibility issues, but you can use bookmarklets as work arounds for user agent styles. i made this little guy here for changing the images background color in chrome:

```
javascript:(function(){%20var%20style=document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML='html%20body%20img.decoded{background:#666%20!important';%20document.body.appendChild(style)%20})();
```

Just copy and paste the above code into your browser as a bookmarklet; i'd name it something like `chrome.img.bg.changer`, but i'm not creative.
Nothing special, but its a solution

Comment: Not a permanent fix but certainly works!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following which will render grey scale around the font

Go to registry

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**

search for  **FontSmoothingGamma**

Double-click mouse on **FONTSMOOTHINGGAMMA** enter anything between 150 and 190 hexadecimal.(the higher the value, the thinner the fonts.)

Make sure cleartype is turned on

**Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization**

[image]

**LOGOFF** and then **LOGON** your system

Now check your chrome browser which makes your black fonts lighter like grey

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why are you talking about font? It's an image. Did you even read the question!?